# time length in VARCHAR mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table where time length type is stored as VARCHAR, and try to select all with longer than 2 and a half hours:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `1970’s Movies`.movies WHERE length;
+----------------------------------+------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| title                            | year | 5-star rating | length      | studio           |
+----------------------------------+------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| Star Wars                        | 1977 |             5 | 2 hr 1 min  | 20th Century Fox |
| National Lampoon’s Animal House  | 1978 |             3 | 1 hr 49 min | Universal        |
| Jaws                             | 1975 |             4 | 2 hr 5 min  | Universal        |
| The Exorcist                     | 1973 |             4 | 2 hr 2 min  | Warner Bros.     |
| Grease                           | 1978 |             2 | 1 hr 50 min | Paramount        |
| The Godfather                    | 1972 |             5 | 2 hr 55 min | Paramount        |
| The Towering Inferno             | 1974 |             3 | 2 hr 45 min | 20th Century Fox |
| The Black Hole                   | 1979 |             1 | 1 hr 38 min | Disney           |
| Superman                         | 1978 |             2 | 2 hr 23 min | Warner Bros.     |
| The Godfather Part II            | 1974 |             5 | 3 hr 20 min | Paramount        |
| Love Story                       | 1970 |             1 | 1 hr 40 min | Paramount        |
+----------------------------------+------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is permissive when converting numbers to strings, so you can make that work for you. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT('2 hr 1 min', UNSIGNED) --> returns 2
```

That will give you the hours. To get the minutes, look three characters after 'hr':

```
SELECT SUBSTR(length, LOCATE('hr', length) + 3) --> returns '1 min' for Star Wars
```

If you apply the convert against '1 min', MySQL will return the number 1.

To show the movie title with hours and minutes, do this:

```
SELECT
  title,
  CONVERT(length, UNSIGNED) AS hours,
  CONVERT(SUBSTR(length, LOCATE('hr', length) + 3), UNSIGNED) as minutes
FROM movies
```

To show only movies more than two and a half hours:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
WHERE CONVERT(length, UNSIGNED) >= 2
  AND CONVERT(SUBSTR(length, LOCATE('hr', length) + 3), UNSIGNED) >= 30
```

Comment: mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM movies
    -> WHERE CONVERT(SUBSTR(length, LOCATE('hr', length) + 3) >= 30;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line
 3

Comment: Sorry - unbalanced parentheses in the minutes conversion. I've updated the answer; give it another try.

Comment: mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM movies
    -> WHERE CONVERT(length, UNSIGNED) > 2
    ->   AND CONVERT(SUBSTR(length, LOCATE('hr', length) + 3)) >= 30;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') >= 30'
at line 4
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') >= 30'
at line 3

Comment: Doh! Terrible re-typing of the queries on my part - I left out the `UNSIGNED` argument for the `CONVERT` of the minutes. I also had `> 2` for hours when it should have been `>= 2`. I've retested the queries and pasted them in directly. Give it another try - this time for sure :)

Comment: Thanks! your help is Amazing on this issue.

Comment: Excellent - glad it worked (finally)! Please upvote and accept the answer if it fully answers your question; that way others who search this site will know it worked.

Comment: another question: How would we add 1 minute to every length? How nice if we can update it as well.

Comment: That's a toughie because of the way the `length` column is formatted. I'm about to sign off for the night, so I'd suggest you post this as a new question if this is a homework assignment. If it's a database you're working on for work/personal purposes, your best bet would be to have separate hour and minute columns; that way you wouldn't have to do a lot of complicated conversions for queries and updates, and you can easily format the two columns into `x hr y min` whenever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The "right" answer is to convert the `length` to a simple number, probably in units of "minutes" *before* storing into the database.  Then format it as you read it back out.

A `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` would be more than adequate; it would handle up to about 1000 hours.

Imagine the complexity if you choose to display the first one as '2:01' instead of '2 hr 1 min'?

What about '2 hr' versus '2 hr 0 min'?